# cargo test with no_std fails with error code 176, 160

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-no-std

Using the below code in main.rs, when I run `cargo test` it returns error code 176, when I add a test or `any statement in main function. It starts returning error code 160.

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

#[cfg(test)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
#[cfg(not(test))]
extern crate panic_halt;

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn main() {

}
```

From this [link](https://community.adobe.com/t5/get-started/re-exit-code-176-not-installing-to-network-drive/td-p/9733238) I found out, that

> Exit code 176 means "Unable to install on a network drive. Select
>   another install location in your preferences and retry installing."

When I tried to find back trace through lldb it returned

> error: invalid thread

I couldn't find any thread which mentions similar error, so asking it here.
Any help is appreciated.

Using nightly (nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin) 
Thanks.

Comment: Your link provided deals with some adobe software. It has **nothing** to do with rust or unix exit codes. So please don't pay attention to that ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `main` function, which has an invalid signature for unix platforms. It must return an `i32` (or better `c_int`, but for simplicity we suppose they are idential).
The `176` is just some random value in the `rax` register when leaving the `main` function.

So change your `main` signature to:

```
pub unsafe extern "C" fn main() -> i32
```

and return a return code (e.g. `0` which means success)

or

```
pub unsafe extern "C" fn main() -> !
```

and use the `exit` syscall on linux (or an infinite loop on embedded systems).

Comment: After adding return 0 and i32 return type as you mentioned, it is not returning error. But is still not executing tests.

Comment: "Running `/Users/xcepti0n/workplace/GitTestRepos/crazy_test/target/debug/deps/crazy-<hash_code>`" after it exits without printing anything.